# Android internationalization

Tags: android, xml, internationalization

I am planning to internationalize my Android app such that the user can choose the language that he wants. However, I will be providing an xml file for the translated words from my server when a client wants to switch from the default language.
What is the best way of incorporating this internationalization methodology in Android?

Answer (score 0):

First thing, from what I recall, it would be difficult to load language specific xml from server. Android design allows you to package these string into xml file and load them from that file stored in res folder. Dynamic loading from server may be harder and not recommended.

You can read up in detail about Android's guidelines for that [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html).

I would also recommend using a professional translating company, it worked well for us but YMMV.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, the point is that the translation is already provided from the server. The plan is to have the same id for words with same meaning, and when the user chooses a language, the xml will have the same ids but with different values so to reflect language change on the UI.

Comment: Hm, to do that then you will need to have a custom string handler that can do this. Also decide if you want to change language when user changes handset language, or prompt user for language change at app launch and then change it. In the latter case have the option to change language in settings menu, in case user wants to change it back. Also note that this a non-standard way to doing this, and plan for more testing and bug fix time.